# Python-requests library still showing default headers after setting custom headers

Tags: python, http, python-requests

Today I was playing with some post data in python, however when trying to set custom headers using the python-requests library and setting the custom headers, it still sends it's default headers, not my custom ones.

```
headers={'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
'User-Agent': 'okhttp/3.5.0',
}
response = requests.post(url,headers,postdata)
```

What appears while inspecting the data with fiddler:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an error in your call to the requests.post function. The correct call could look like this:

```
requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=postdata)
```

Changing this in the code you provided should result in requests sending your custom headers.